# Can I write$~~~\forall~\text{const}\in\mathbb{R}\setminus\left\{0\right\}~~$for an arbitrary constant of eigenvector?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, notation

$$A:=n*n~~~~~\text{matrix with}~\color{red}{A_{i,j}\in\mathbb{R}~~\leftarrow~~~~~~\text{Added the condition.}}$$

As the eigenvector of some$~\lambda~$of$~A~$is as below, then which set does it include the non-zero arbitraty constant?set of real numbers?or set of complex numbers?
$$\begin{bmatrix}x_{1}\\x_{2}\\x_{3}\\\end{bmatrix}=~~~~\text{const}\begin{bmatrix}1\\3\\5\\\end{bmatrix}$$

$$\boldsymbol{x}_{}=\begin{bmatrix}x_{1}\\x_{2}\\x_{3}\\\end{bmatrix}~~\leftarrow~~~~~~\text{eigenvector}$$
$$~~~~\text{const}~~~~~\text{is a nonzero arbitrary constant}$$
Why I am asking this question is that, it is too time-taking to write
$$~~~~\text{const}~~~~~\text{is a nonzero arbitrary constant}$$
rather than writing(at here, I assume that set of real numbers is the correct set)
$$\forall~\text{const}\in\mathbb{R}\setminus\left\{0\right\}$$
Can I conclude that the correct set is$\mathbb{R}$?

**ADD(After I've read the post of answer)**

$$\displaystyle A\boldsymbol{x}_{}=
 \begin{bmatrix}
 a_{11}&a_{12}&a_{13}\\
 a_{21}&a_{22}&a_{23}\\
 a_{31}&a_{32}&a_{33}\\
 \end{bmatrix}
 \begin{bmatrix}
 x_{1}\\x_{2}\\x_{3}\\
 \end{bmatrix}=\lambda\begin{bmatrix}
 x_{1}\\x_{2}\\x_{3}\\
 \end{bmatrix}=\lambda\boldsymbol{x}_{}
$$

I intuitively know that eigenvector of$~A~$is always real.

$$\lambda\in\mathbb{R}$$

> One answer is that it depends. Formally eigenvalues and eigenvectors of matrices only make sense when we fix a vector space of column vectors for them to act on:

So you mean that writing

$$\forall~\text{const}\in\mathbb{C}\setminus\left\{0\right\}$$

is always correct?

Answer (score 2):

One answer is that it depends. Formally eigenvalues and eigenvectors of matrices only make sense when we fix a vector space of column vectors for them to act on: if our $n \times n$ matrices only have real entries, we could have our matrices act on $\mathbb{R}^n$ or $\mathbb{C}^n$, with corresponding possible eigenvalues in $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$. (Of course it doesn't make sense to have a matrix with general complex entries act on $\mathbb{R}^n$.) Most of the time, in an application, what is desired is clear.

Another answer which you might like more is to do with the fact that $\mathbb{C}$ is something called the *algebraic closure* of $\mathbb{R}$. A consequence of this is that even though we can sometimes gain extra eigenvalues by changing from viewing a matrix with real entries as acting on real column vectors into instead acting on complex column vectors, there is no "bigger" field $\mathbb{k}$ which we could pass to after passing to $\mathbb{C}$ in which we would pick up any more eigenvalues. So it is always safe to talk about the eigenvalues of a matrix with real entries lying in $\mathbb{C}$ without missing any information.

It also appears to me that you are under the impression that eigenvalues are nonzero: this is not true. It is only eigenvectors which must be nonzero (i.e. in your example above "$\text{const}$" does not have to be nonzero to be an eigenvalue for the eigenvector $\begin{bmatrix}1\\3\\5\end{bmatrix}$).